# php 5.2.17 source code repository

Tags: php

The php developers do not support anymore php 5.2.17. However, normal apps are using this php instead of the new one, 5.3 branch (Whose idea was drop security support for 5.2.17? ). Normally we compile php from source code. However the official source code is outdated. Is there any public repository out there with backported patchs?

edit: I mean, my brother's repository is not valid. We are asking if any public and well known repository is available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with the PHP sources of Debian Lenny available on http://packages.debian.org/lenny/php5

http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main//php5/php5_5.2.6.dfsg.1.orig.tar.gz

However, you **MUST** upgrade your application to support PHP 5.3, or sky will fall on your head.

Comment: note that debian drops support for lenny this month, so this is a REALLY temporary solution (especially seeing the rate at which these vulnerabilities are being discovered).

Answer (score 0):

In response to myself, to the post and to other users, i know about the distro repos but, you know, they are not 5.2.17, (5.2.6 or 5.2.3). Maybe in Ubuntu  but i dont know atm.

I have seen http://code.google.com/p/php52-backports/ . I think it is used by freebsd developers but i still could not confirm it . It would be perfect .